# How do I access a class variable in another class?

Tags: symbols

Complete java noob, right here. Currently teaching myself. Recently, I tried making a basic program that would use a class to take info from another class, and print it out. I keep getting this error:

```
error cannot find symbol

System.out.print1n(ljames.weight);

symbol: variable weight
location: class ljames
```

Here is my code:

http://shrib.com/sEyGhFZr

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just the visibility of variables. You did not declare these variables to be public and are inaccessible for other classes.

You declared your functions to be public, they are accessible from somewhere else.

I recommend to create a public constructor and create get-accessors for your variables. You set them via constructor and read them via get-accessor. This way you keep your data safe and you are still able to change when you need.

```
class Data {
    String height;
    int weight;
    int depth;
    public Data(String height, int weight, int depth) {
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.depth = depth;
    }
    public string getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I think I was getting way in over my head. I am currently learning from the book "Sam's Teach yourself Java in 21 Days". Everything is new to me. Took a while to wrap my mind around the fundementals object oriented programming. Anyways, I'm on day 4: List, Logic, and Loops. Turns out I learn constructors on day 6. lol. Rushing myself.

Comment: @AbdiAbdalla The beginning is true pain. When you finally mastered your fifth language everything becomes to look the same and you don't have any problems anymore. :) (I am a novice in Java myself. ^^)

Answer (score 0):

The class **ljames** has no field named **weight** as this is in the **Data** class.

Comment: He overrides the class name with a variable of type `Data` inside of the main function. It's lack of visibility which causes problems. But you are right, he should rename either the class or the variable.

Comment: The code that I see when clicking on the link is not having any Ijames extends Data nor does it have any "new ljames()" in it. Its kind of confusing.